# What is the Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1-\left(a_1 x+... + o(x^n)\right)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

What is the Taylor expansion of the function $f(x)$ near $x=0$?
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1-g(x)}
$$ 
where $g(x)$ is already a Taylor expansion at order $n>1$ (near $x=0$):
$$
g(x) = a_1 x +...+a_n x^n + o(x^n)
$$
with $a_1\neq 0$.

---

If we use the well known Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1-X}$ at order $m\geq1$ with $X=g(x)$ we obtain:
$$
f(x) = 1 + g(x) + g(x)^2 + ... + g(x)^m + o\left(g(x)^m\right)
$$

I feel like a lot of terms can be discarded, but I am not sure which ones.
I am not comfortable with the expression $o\left(g(x)^m\right)$.

Is it true that $o\left(g(x)^m\right) = o\left(x^{\min(n,m)}\right)$?

Answer (score 1):

To actually get the coefficients of
$g(x)$, write it as
$1 = f(1-g)
=f-fg$
so
$fg = f-1$.

Expand the left side
by the standard formula
for the product of polynomials
to get a recurrence
for the coefficients of $g$.

This will take about
$n$ operations to get
the coefficient of $x^n$.

I'd do it
but I am on my phone.